# Is it possible to have 2 default locations one for CTAS (CREATE TABLE AS SELECT ) and other for CREATE TABLE in hive?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive

I am changing a configuration to the `hiveserver2-site.xml` as below:

`hive.metastore.warehouse.dir = <new s3 bucket>.`

Currently all clusters use common default location but we want to override the default location to two specific clusters. So I made this change to that cluster's `hiveserver2-site.xml`.

When I restart the `hiveserver2` and test, CTAS(CREATE TABLE AS SELECT ) is picking the new bucket but CREATE TABLE still uses the old location.

Not able to understand the difference in the default locations. Can anyone please explain.

Comment: You need to stop and start all hadoop service in that cluster to make that change effective. If you are doing these changes using Ambari, it tells you to restart all required services

Comment: we are not using Ambari. I restarted hiveserver2 and hive metastore servers (we have two metastore servers, one is for read-write and the other is for read-only). Now the CTAS is using the new bucket location and as well writing data to that location but describe formatted <ctas table> shows the location as old bucket (but data is not written to it). And, when i try select list on that table, it is trying to fetch the data from old bucket and retrieving 0 rows. FYI set hive.metastore.warehouse.dir gives new s3 bucket location itself. Can anyone please help me with a solution.